# How to refactor a codebase that uses spring autowiring

Tags: java, spring, refactoring, autowired

I've inherited two fairly non-trivial codebases that uses spring for configuring the applications. Now I need to reconfigure the applications. But lots of the configuration is provided through autowiring so it is almost impossible to find out what the actual configuration is.

The projects are moderately sized, some 20-ish maven modules per project including  integration test modules and such. Most modules define a few application contexts for various purposes, that contain one or two local spring config files along with one or two from the core modules it depends on. The result is a myriad of configurations, and that I cannot alter a class or variable name (or setter method) without risking breaking dependencies in some upstream or downstream module, even if no such dependency is visible anywhere in the project.

How do I work effectively with autowired dependencies in spring?

Can anyone, perhaps someone who actually likes autowiring, provide some insight into how you work with them effectively?

(I also inherited a small project that combines xml-files, autowiring and annotation-driven config, making dependency relations completely intractable, but I'll save those annotations for a separate question later)

Comment: can you turn on spring logging and get clues as to what beans it's instantiating when it processes the application context xml files?

Comment: I guess the total amount of different application contexts in a project is like 50 or so. Some are even used only inside fitnesse fixtures (in a process spawned by a spawned process ...) and some only inside web apps. It is certainly possible, but it would take the entire day for a single dependency. Building all modules and running all the requirements tests takes at least one hour. With all dependencies declared in xml (not that I like xml, it is only less bad than the alternatives...) it takes at most 2 minutes to track down all the uses for a single method or class.

Comment: for that matter you could write code to parse the spring log files and create an application-context.xml from that. that sounds like it might almost be useful.

Comment: No. There is not "one application context". The project builds several applications, one of them integrating with 5 others. I have test configs for integrating with one-by-one of those (no place where all are available as test systems simultaneously), inserting mocks for unavailable remote systems. I have configs for running against requirement tests one-by-one with visual inspections from a web browser, and for running the same "headless" on a CI server, with or without asynch queues inside. Counted that way it is around 15 applications/configurations that all must work.

Comment: There are people actually liking autowiring? I thought autowiring was only for demo purposes so the HelloWorld gets shorter

Comment: @doc_180 had the answer: You cannot safely refactor a project with autowired dependencies, but there are tools that can help you turn by-coincidence object relations into declared dependency relations. Then you can refactor safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform re-factoring of auto wired beans using Intellij (I have version 9 Ultimate). Also Intellij has an option of making autowiring dependencies explicit. Link Provided below

http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/03/making-spring-autowired-dependencies-explicit/

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using?  Spring STS (an Eclipse based IDE) has a lot of tools for working with Spring annotations and autowiring as well as good set of refactoring tools.

Comment: I use IntelliJ ultimate 10. It has the best spring-support that I am aware of, but it still doesn't detect it if renaming a setter method would break an autowired-by-name relationship.

Comment: The more I use it the more I hate this configuration-by-coincidence mechanism